# Decrypting a text encrypted with aes128 cipher algorithm

Tags: aes, password-cracking, decryption

I found this challenge from a CS academy site and I was intrigued:
A message was encrypted using the following openSSL command. What is the password used to encrypt the message? What is the secret message?

```
$ openssl enc –aes128 –base64 < secret-message 
U2FsdGVkX180jAizsYGu5mZo9zSrzchodLCgKNl4j/PRNW4htplDZ/yKekDc5mZSsMaO+sOleP/S0HWw/AuemWLTseXiL1nWR920vgTc7g/+mBfVYB991loGTkAuMuwQ
```

I know that AES is uncrackable in practice (because it would take too much time to try all the combinations) but I was wondering if any of you have some ideas what else could I try to solve it. Since it is a task with educational aspect I assume the password can't be that difficult.

So far I have tried a dictionary attack using openssl enc decryption. For dictionary I used well known darkC0de.txt . I wrote a simple bash script that would try all the passwords in the dictionary. Unfortunately all I got was a lot of false positive decryptions. 
Does anyone have any ideas what else could I try? It might be possible that this is not meant to be solved and the answer is that, you cant do it.

Comment: Why is this offtopic? I did not ask anyone to break the challenges security. I merely asked additional ideas which I obviously did not get. Also one can read that I tried dictionary attack which did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to give you the solution, just let you know where you're going wrong.

It would really have helped if you had provided some context.
The challenge comes from one of:

- [this page](https://secureset.com/core/challenges/)
- [the pdf](http://securesetacademy.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/TechnicalAssessmentWorksheet_Digital_V2.pdf) version

Seems like you used the web page since you included the `-` between lines. You need to remove that.
Also: the pdf contains a hint without which you could be searching forever as opposed to minutes (to write the program and run it).

However, don't copy/paste the pdf version, there are three switched characters in there. I don't know who the people behind this stuff are, but they're sloppy.

The fixed web version does decode into something once you find the right password. Not sure it makes sense though, there must be some inside joke I'm missing.

Comment: Please don't use an answer post to give a non answer to an off topic question.

Comment: I agree it's off-topic. I disagree about the non-answer part. The OP asked about what else could be tried to solve a puzzle, not the actual answer to the puzzle. I provided more than enough information for the OP to solve the original problem.

Comment: You did not actually provide any helpful information. I know that '-' is a mistake in there since base64 does not have '-' symbol in its encoding. I would have not gotten any false positives if I would have not removed that and known that. It would not simply decode if you have '-' in the encrypted message. I think it gave "bad magic number" error.